# Github Actions - Getting Could not Write Error on Allure Report

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, github-actions, allure

I am having project where it is using following :

1. Java - 11
2. Maven
3. TestNG
4. Selenium Webdriver
5. Allure Report

Everything works fine on local machine but when I run on Github actions , I am getting error and allure report is not being generated.

Error is :

```
 io.qameta.allure.AllureResultsWriteException: Could not write Allure test result container
Error:      at io.qameta.allure.FileSystemResultsWriter.write(FileSystemResultsWriter.java:68)
Error:      at io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle.writeTestContainer(AllureLifecycle.java:170)
Error:      at io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg.onFinish(AllureTestNg.java:195)
Error:      at org.testng.SuiteRunner.invokeListeners(SuiteRunner.java:269)
Error:      at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:332)
Error:      at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
Error:      at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
Error:      at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
Error:      at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
Error:      at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
Error:      at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
Error:      at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
Error:      at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
Error:      at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
Error:      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
Error:      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
Error:      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Error:  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: allure-results/94d424ca-48b8-454e-b49d-d398a77c5cab-container.json (Permission denied)
Error:      at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
Error:      at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
Error:      at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
Error:      at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
Error:      at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TokenStreamFactory._fileOutputStream(TokenStreamFactory.java:278)
Error:      at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createGenerator(JsonFactory.java:1369)
Error:      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.createGenerator(ObjectMapper.java:1230)
Error:      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3811)
Error:      at io.qameta.allure.FileSystemResultsWriter.write(FileSystemResultsWriter.java:66)
Error:      ... 16 more
```

Below is my Github YML file :

```
# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven, and cache/restore any dependencies to improve the workflow execution time
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-java-with-maven

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

name: Stage - Automation

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Install Google Chrome #Using shell script to install Google Chrome
      run:   |
              chmod +x ./scripts/InstallChrome.sh
                          ./scripts/InstallChrome.sh
                          
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn test -P placeOrder_stage -Denv=stage


    - name: Test marketplace action
      uses: simple-elf/allure-report-action@master
      if: always()
      id: allure-report
      with:
        allure_results: allure-results/Reports/*
        gh_pages: gh-pages
        allure_report: allure-report
        allure_history: allure-history


    - name: Deploy report to Github Pages
      if: always()
      uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v2
      env:
        PERSONAL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        PUBLISH_BRANCH: gh-pages
        PUBLISH_DIR: allure-history
```

Comment: Just a suggestion but from my experience, usually it requires that you create the folder allure-results and chmod it as well in a step prior to writting to it.

At least this is how it is done when using our self-hosted runners, but it is worth a try.

Comment: @JCompetence - Can you please share some reference how to do that? As I am not much good on yml and linux commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the step:

**- name: Update allure-results folder permissions**

as shown below.

jobs:
build:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Set up JDK 11
  uses: actions/setup-java@v3
  with:
    java-version: '11'
    distribution: 'temurin'
    cache: maven
- name: Install Google Chrome #Using shell script to install Google Chrome
  run:   |
          chmod +x ./scripts/InstallChrome.sh
                      ./scripts/InstallChrome.sh
                      
- name: Build with Maven
  run: mvn test -P placeOrder_stage -Denv=stage





- name: Update allure-results folder permissions
  run: |
         mkdir -p allure-results/Reports/
         chmod 777 -R allure-results/Reports/
            





- name: Test marketplace action
  uses: simple-elf/allure-report-action@master
  if: always()
  id: allure-report
  with:
    allure_results: allure-results/Reports/*
    gh_pages: gh-pages
    allure_report: allure-report
    allure_history: allure-history


- name: Deploy report to Github Pages
  if: always()
  uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v2
  env:
    PERSONAL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    PUBLISH_BRANCH: gh-pages
    PUBLISH_DIR: allure-history
```